# How to put the name of my advisor in my thesis?

Tags: formatting, titles

I would like the name of my advisor to appear under mine (2 lines down and in the center), in the front page of my thesis... I really do not know how to do it....
Thanks for any help.

My work is the following :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=20mm,bottom=50mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\addbibresource{reffence.bib}







\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}}

\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[section]


\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Παράδειγμα~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}




\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead{}
\setlength{\headheight}{107pt}

\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{logoeap.jpg}\\Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας του \textlatin{Alexandrov} για Κλειστά και Κυρτά Πολύεδρα, Δημήτριος Στεργίου}

\graphicspath{{images/}}





\title{
{\emph{Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας του \textlatin{Alexandrov} για Κλειστά και Κυρτά Πολύεδρα}}\\





{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{logoeap.jpg}}}
\author[1]{Δημήτρης Στεργίου}

\date{Νοέμβριος 2021}












\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}





\begin{document}
\maketitle


\chapter*{Περίληψη}
.................

\chapter*{Αφιέρωση}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to do using `tabular`.

[image: b]

```
\author{\begin{tabular}{c}
    Δημήτρης Στεργίου\\[14.5pt]
    Σύμβουλος: Ευκλείδης Αλεξανδρείας 
\end{tabular}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `maketitle` like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=20mm,bottom=50mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}





\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tipa}
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}}

\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Λήμμα}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[section]


\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Παράδειγμα~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}




\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead{}
\setlength{\headheight}{107pt}

\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{logoeap.jpg}\\Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας του \textlatin{Alexandrov} για Κλειστά και Κυρτά Πολύεδρα, Δημήτριος Στεργίου}






\title{
{\emph{Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας του \textlatin{Alexandrov} για Κλειστά και Κυρτά Πολύεδρα}}\\





{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{logoeap.jpg}}}
\author[1]{Δημήτρης Στεργίου}

\date{Νοέμβριος 2021}












\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \LARGE
    \@title \\[2cm]
    \large
    \@author \\[1cm]
    Advisor Name \\[2cm]
    \@date
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{center}
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\mytitlepage


\chapter*{Περίληψη}
.................

\chapter*{Αφιέρωση}
\end{document}
```

and replace "Advisor Name" by the actual name.
Is it what you want ?